# Defining a val in terms of the member of an abstract val (Scala bug?)

Tags: scala

I came across a runtime error and was wondering whether this is a bug in Scala, or if it shouldn't at least be caught during compile time.
This code produces a NullPointerException:

```
object Main extends App {
  trait A {
    val data: { val x: Int }
    val x = data.x
  }
  val a = new A {
    val data = new Object { val x = 42 }
  }
  a.x
}
```

Of course it's easy to fix by making A.x lazy or a `def`, but as obvious as that may be in this minimal example, in more realistic code it can be a little perplexing.

Comment: What does `val data: { val x: Int }` mean in Scala?

Comment: This must be a duplicate, because the answer is always the same: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

Comment: @yannbane just something with a member x.

Comment: @som-snytt could you elaborate? This doesn't really help me know what it is, only how it behaves. Is it some form of pattern matching? If someone has a more authoritative answer that'd be great.

Comment: @yannbane the term is "structural type". Actually, "something with a member x" tells you neither what it is, nor how it behaves, but only something about its structure. 3.2.7 in the spec says if a refinement isn't an override, it's structural. This example is `AnyRef { val x: Int }` by definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is confusing when you encounter it for the first time, but it is expected behaviour.

The normal initialization order is that vals in super traits are initialized first. In your example this means that `val x` in trait A gets initialized before `val data` in your anonymous subclass, therefore causing a NullPointer.

If you want to make your example work you have to use a feature called "Early Defintions" (5.1.6 in the language specification).

In your concrete example this is the syntax you'd need to use:

```
val a = new {
  val data = new Object { val x = 42 }
} with A
```

This initializes the data val before initializing the vals in A.

Comment: It's worth noting there are other options, per the faq in the comment, and the best change is, per the faq, to use defs in traits or lazy vals. FTR, SO should notify up-voters with comments and other amendments: You thought this was a complete answer, but here is more info for you.

Comment: I totally agree, I kind of answered in a somewhat narrow way. Is it common practice on SO to significantly enhance an already accepted answer? I certainly would not mind doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten that this option is mentioned in the one-question FAQ.

```
$ scala -Xcheckinit
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-RC1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> object Main extends App {
     |   trait A {
     |     val data: { val x: Int }
     |     val x = data.x
     |   }
     |   val a = new A {
     |     val data = new Object { val x = 42 }
     |   }
     |   a.x
     | }
<console>:15: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
         a.x
           ^
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
defined object Main

scala> Main main null
scala.UninitializedFieldError: Uninitialized field: <console>: 13
  at Main$$anon$1.data(<console>:13)
  at Main$A$class.$init$(<console>:10)
  ... 43 elided
```